# How do you connect python's websocket-client to nodejs socket server

Tags: python, node.js, websocket

As soon as I try to connect I am getting error --- response header --- Connection is already closed.

I am connecting from a python client using pip install websocket-client
My websocket server is running on nodejs

I can connect from my web browser using javscript to my server successfully but not with a python client

Python client code:

```
import websocket

def on_message(ws, message):
    print(message)

def on_error(ws, error):
    print(error)

def on_close(ws):
    print("### closed ###")

def on_open(ws):
    print("Open")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp("ws://localhost:5000",
                              on_message = on_message,
                              on_error = on_error,
                              on_close = on_close)
    ws.on_open = on_open
    ws.run_forever()
```

Error:

--- request header ---
GET / HTTP/1.1
Upgrade: websocket
Host: localhost:5000
Origin: http://localhost:5000
Sec-WebSocket-Key: 142ZQUrD0t0w2kwLIkLZag==
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Connection: upgrade

--- response header ---

Connection is already closed.

Note: my server is running and and my javascript client does connect.

Any ideaas?